# Complexity of Haemers' minimum rank

Tags: np-hardness, graph-colouring

In 1978 Willem H. Haemmers published "[An upper bound on the Shannon capacity of a graph](http://arno.uvt.nl/show.cgi?fid=80314)".

Tims has a survey of more recent results [his thesis](http://orion.math.iastate.edu/lhogben/GeoffTimsThesis.pdf).

What is the computational complexity of computing Haemmer's minimum rank function?

Comment: I think this is the python code Timms used in his thesis if it is of any help in wrapping your head around the problem. https://github.com/jasongrout/minimum_rank/blob/master/minrank.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computing min rank is NP-hard:

- Rene Peeters, "[Orthogonal Representation over Finite Fields and the Chromic Numbr of Graphs](http://arno.uvt.nl/show.cgi?fid=95878)", 1996.
- Salim Y. El Rouayheb, Mohammad Asad R. Chaudhry, Alex Sprintson, "[On the Minimum Number of Transmissions in Single-Hop Wireless Coding Networks](http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.0860v1)", 2007.